# Why does my enemy is not chasing me at all when i tell him to stop chasing me when his hp is at 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a problem in my code which i dont understand and i cant find a solution.The problem is when i add the line of code `if(distToPlayer > agroRange || currentHealth <= 0){ StopChasingPlayer}`The enemy will stop chasing me at all,like the script is not working anymore,in the debugger i can see that it is inside the if cuz it keeps sending me the message of the Debug.Log
There are the two scripts that contain the health and the enemy agro

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{   

    
    private EnemyAgro enemyAgro;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public Transform spawnPos;
    public GameObject spawnItem;
    public Animator animator;
    public event EventHandler OnHealthChanged;
    public int health;
    private int healthMax = 20;

    public void Start(){
        health = healthMax;
        
        
        
    }

    void Update(){
        health = health; 
    }

    
    public void HealthSystem(int healthMax){
        this.healthMax = healthMax;
        health = healthMax;

    }

    public int GetHealth(){
        return health;
    }

    public float GetHealthPercent(){
        return (float)health/healthMax;
    }
    public void Damage(int damageAmount){
        health -= damageAmount;
        if(health < 0) health =0;
        if(OnHealthChanged != null) OnHealthChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public void Heal(int healAmount){
        health += healAmount;
        if (health > healthMax)health = healthMax;
        if(OnHealthChanged != null) OnHealthChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage){
        health -= damage;
        animator.SetTrigger("Hurt");
       
        if(health<= 0){
            Die(); 

        }
    }
     void Die(){
        Debug.Log("DIED");

        animator.SetBool("IsDead",true);

        GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled=false;
        this.enabled = false;
        if(health <= 0){
            
            GetComponent<EnemyAgro>().enabled= false;
            gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
            Instantiate(spawnItem, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
            
        }
            
        }
        public int Health(){
            return health;
        }
       
}
```

```
And the enemy agro...
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAgro : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    public GameObject Enemy;
    private EnemyHealth enemyHealth;
    private int curentHealth;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform player;
    [SerializeField]
    float agroRange;
    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed;

    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

     public void Start()
    {
        enemyHealth = enemyHealth.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        curentHealth = enemyHealth.health;
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
     void Update()
    {    
        
        
        float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if(distToPlayer < agroRange){
            ChasePlayer();
        }
        if(distToPlayer > agroRange || currentHealth <= 0){
            Debug.Log("Chase Stoped");
            StopChasingPlayer();
        }
        
    }

    private void ChasePlayer(){
        
        if(transform.position.x < player.position.x){
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed,0);
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1,1);
            
        }
        else if(transform.position.x > player.position.x){
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed,0);
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1,1);
        }
        }
    

    public void StopChasingPlayer(){
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }


    }
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug your own code using the **[awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: But the problem is not that the code isnt working or has errors.The problem is that i doesnt do what i tell him to do and i dont have the required knowledge to fix that

Comment: What's the problem here? You tell him to stop then he stops? The question does not explain what the problem is.

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you tell it to do. If you don't understand what you are doing wrong, using the debugger will tell you.

Comment: Btw what is this line/method for `void Update(){health = health; }` ? ^^

Comment: Umm it was for the health update every frame so the EnemyAgro script knows always the value of the health...idk if its dump but in my mind was ok ^_^

Comment: And as i said there is no error in the debugger thats why i am asking here...if there was an error i would google it

Answer (score 1):

The only time you are getting the actual current enemy health in EnemyAgro is in your Start() method. You aren't getting updated values later, in Update().

Remember, start is only called when your component is initialized...from then on, only Update is called every frame by the engine.

Set curentHealth = enemyHealth.Health in your update() function.

Or, even better, just change the code in your update statement to

```
    void Update()
    {
        float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if(distToPlayer < agroRange && enemyHealth.health > 0){
            ChasePlayer();
         else
         {
             StopChasingPlayer();
         }   

    }
```

Comment: Ye i did it but as i said...when i put it in if (The enemyHealth.health > 0) it is not chasing me...i tried puting in in both ifs with different conditions (e.g )


`if(distToPlayer < agroRange || enemyHealth.health >= 0){
            ChasePlayer();
         if(distToPlayer < agroRange || enemyHealth.health <= 0){
         {
             StopChasingPlayer();
         }   `